# Ambiguous route ordering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have two ambiguous routes, both within the same MVC area:

```
Default
{controller}/{action}/{id}
controller = "Home"
action     = "Index"
id         = Optional

SettingsRoute
Settings/{controller}/{action}
action     = "Index"
```

I want MVC to use the `Default` route by default, which it does when the routes are in the order specified above. So this...

```
Controller: WelcomeController
Action: Login

using( Html.BeginForm() ) { }
```

...results in this HTML

```
<form action="/Welcome/Login" method="post"></form>
```

So far, so good.

However when I have an anchor that looks like this:

```
<a href="Settings/AppSettings">Application settings</a>
```

...it gets captured by the `Default` route as `Controller = Settings, Action = AppSettings` instead of by the `SettingsRoute` route.

When I reorder the routes so `SettingsRoute` appears before `Default` then my `Html.BeginForm()` calls look like this: `<form action="Settings/Welcome/Login">` which isn't what I want at all.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: If both are within the same area then why do you need the extra route when it's definition is the same as the default route? The problem is that you have include the `{controller}` part and the engine picks up `Settings` as an additional part of the route.

Answer (score 0):

You Can mention <%:Html.ActionLink("Create Item-->this is the page you wanted to redirec ","Index","Item--> folder of the page") %>
 You can Navigate from one page to another.